# Where does the incoming Cable/Internet service provider wire (Comcast in my case), get terminated in my low voltage panel?

Tags: internet, services

I was wondering where the incoming cable/service providers wire actually lands on a low voltage panel. It is a residential application & I'd like to learn more on how service actually gets passed through the main terminations, through patch panels, & onto routers/outlets.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Usually they offer you to choose the outlet location somewhere in your home. If you have already existing cables in your home they will use those.

Comment: The demarc is outside the house, usually, as Jack's answer states. Unless you've managed to jam their modem/router into your low voltage panel, often there's no direct connection there - certainly for the internet part, cable signal hits a cable modem (which may also have a router, wifi, and a switch built into it.) In the minds of the masses those are all one thing called a router, and the masses are wrong... After passing though the router and a switch, you have ethernet that can connect to a patch panel, but if you have more than a few ports you need another switch to feed the patch panel.

Comment: If you are so archaic as to actually use the cable TV signal for anything other than internet, that signal comes in, gets split by a splitter, and coaxial cables go off to outlets. Each time the signal is split the level drops, so if you are splitting it a lot, you may need an amplifier - which is usually not compatible with your internet, so the cable modem needs to get split off first, and then you can amplify and split the remaining half of the signal to provide for your archaic "Cable TV as Cable TV" needs.

Comment: Learning about how internet service works inside a house is far more the domain of Super User than DIY. I've requested a mod migrate the question, if it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

Comcast will mount a connection box on the outside of your house, front or back depending on where their easement is. From there, it's your wire that would go to your low voltage panel inside your house if your house is pre wired. If not, they might run it, for a price, or tell you to run it. From your panel, you'll have a number of parallel wired sockets or patches that you  will use to connect to your router, TV cable box,etc.

Comment: DO NOT let Bombastic cable (comcast) do ANY wiring on your house other than to the demark box on the outside of your house.   They ARE BUTCHERS: Staple the cable outside the house drill into where the outlet will be, carve out a hole and put a cheap ass trim plate on it screwed into sheetrock. Then squirt the hole where the cable enters the house with some silicone and call it a day.  Hopefully you have your house already wired for various low voltage needs.